# Problem on executing firmware from Bank2 on STM32 Dual-Bank flash

Tags: embedded, stm32, firmware

I'm currently working with the STM32L073RZ on a project that requires firmware update over a proprietary wireless protocol. The OTA method I'm working on is using the dual-bank feature of this MCU. I managed to successfully program BANK2 with the new firmware which is completely different from BANK1 firmware in terms peripherals used and overall functionality. My problem is that when i set the BFB2=1 to boot from BANK2 the MCU fails to execute the firmware.

I did some more tests by only programming BANK2 and trying to boot from it without having any firmware in BANK1 and still no luck. What am i doing wrong? Do i need a certain code to be programmed to BANK1 even if i don't want to use this bank at all? What part of the code from BANK1 is the MCU using when it's running the firmware in BANK2?

I should mention that I've read the ST's AN4767 and AN2606 documents on this matter. Also when i program two identical firmware on both banks (compiled with different linker scripts to match the bank address) and slightly change the code to identify which one is executing(ex. one bank led blink and one led on), everything works fine from both BANKS.

Comment: If your vector table is anywhere other than 0x0 then you'll need to set the CPU's `VTOR` register to point to it. I guess in the case with identical firmware in each bank, you'd be running code from BANK2 but your interrupt vectors in BANK1, which might work.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried to set the VTOR register (by adding SCB->VTOR = 0x08018000 in the main function) to the start of the bank2 which i assume is the start of the vector table in the bank2 firmware but it still didn't work.  Am i doing this correctly or should i set it to anything else?

Comment: As far as I know that is that all that should be required (regarding VTOR). I'd suggest using a debugger to see what is going on. Also, STM32CubeProgrammer can read and interpret all the Cortex debug registers if there is a hard fault.

Comment: I'll try manipulating the VTOR in different ways to see if i get it to work. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @mehdihfzp have you set the value of the vector table offset in the system file ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the problem. In my case i didn't pay attention to `SYSCFG_CFGR1_UFB` register. I was trying to switch the bank with the BFB2 register and also built the firmware for the address of bank2 which is wrong. Actually didn't know that when i switch the bank, the second bank's address will be always be bound to virtual address 0x08000000.
Thanks to all the experts who have participated in this topic.